# Getting error in Tridion while accessing core services

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, tridion-core-services

Could not find endpoint element with name 'wsHttp' and contract 'Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.ISessionAwareCoreService' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this name could be found in the client element

while accessing:

ISessionAwareCoreService client = new ChannelFactory("wsHttp").CreateChannel();

Comment: Perhaps you can include your web/app.config file and specify your version of Tridion.

Comment: Interesting question, could we interest you in committing to the [Area 51 Tridion specific proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion?referrer=gPujQMxthNCNn9xqeeO2NA2). Sign up with the same SO account if you have a moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write software using the Tridion core service, you need to do one of two things:

1. Create a configuration file for your application that contains the correct WCF configuration
2. Set up the WCF settings in your software by writing code.

If you are creating a config file, then you can start by copying the default one provided by Tridion. On my system this is at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Tridion\bin\client\Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.dll.config`

If your core service client is running on the Tridion server itself, that will probably be sufficient. If you are "off the box" then you'll need to edit it appropriately.

If you want to set things up from code, a good place to start is [this recipe in the Tridion Cookbook](http://code.google.com/p/tridion-practice/wiki/GetCoreServiceClientWithoutConfigFile). (There's also [a recipe for the non-code approach.](http://code.google.com/p/tridion-practice/wiki/GetCoreServiceClientWithConfigFile))